# rescue Ubuntu 11.04 from overwritten system files

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, initrd

I accidentaly extracted an ArchLinux initrd to / . Now the system won't boot anymore.

How do I reinstall the overwritten system files? Can I use an apt-command for this? I still can chroot into the system using Ubuntu live cd recovery.

Reinstalling the system is not quite possible.

Thank you!

Yvan